# Create Trigger based on Status change in column and insert value in another column for a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table named as `Employee` which has columns like `Status` and `Expected_Promotion_Date`

The `Status column` is populated from `StatusEnum` which has values like `Level 1`, `Level 2`, and `Level 3`.
When the `Status` of `Employee` changes from `Level 1` to `Level 2`, I need a `trigger` that populates a value in the `Expected_Promotion_Date` column i.e. current date plus 3 years.

I tried making the trigger, please find the reference code for the same:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER Expected_Promotion_Date 
    AFTER   
    UPDATE OF STATUS FOR EACH ROW   
     DECLARE    NEXT_MAINTENANCE_CONTROL DATE;   
BEGIN     
   IF(:OLD.STATUS<>:NEW.STATUS) THEN     
    BEGIN   
      IF(:OLD.STATUS=-10 AND :NEW.STATUS=00)THEN         
     BEGIN  

     END      
  END   
END
```

Can someone please help me with the `trigger` as I am new to it and learning it from the first time. If someone can help me with it or guide me for the same, it would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ankit - pease [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67332449/edit) to add your code as formatted text. Also include the table definition, and explain what is wrong with your code - if it errors, or doesn't do what you expect, etc.

Comment: @APC `Level 1` has intValue of -10 and `Level 2` has intValue of 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create or replace trigger expected_promotion_date 
before update on employee for each row   
begin     

  if :old.status != :new.status then 
    :new.expected_promotion_date := trunc(sysdate) + interval '3' year;
  end if; 

end;
/
```

This code checks whether the value of STATUS has changed, and if it's different populates expected promotion date column with today's date plus three years.

---

You may need to tweak this code to handle any other business logic which you haven't included in your question. For instance, in your comment you show some logic relating to the value of STATUS. I've ignored that, as you haven't explained what is supposed to happen. The usefulness of the answer we can give is proportional to the clarity of the question.

Comment: Got it mate, cant upvote since the low reputation count, will mark it as correct, I am trying to tweak it actually. Once again thank you!

Comment: You should be able to upvote answers to your own question? Not that I need the rep but other people might

Comment: @APC you might want to do a check for NULL values.

Comment: @KoenLostrie - they're not my rules, it's for the Seeker to define the requirements :)